# Python 3.4: Loop and Append: Why Not Working With cx_Oracle and Pandas?

Tags: pandas, cx-oracle

For some reason, the following code only returns a dataframe of 10 rows instead of 20 (there are millions of rows in the SQL view). 
When I viewed the output from print(data2), it showed the first 10 rows as a DataFrame, but the next DataFrame was empty.

```
import cx_Oracle as cx
import pandas as pd
conn = cx.Connection("username/pwd@server")

data = pd.DataFrame([])
SQL1 = '''SELECT * FROM TABLE_MV where rownum between '''
for i in range(1, 20, 10):
    lower = i
    upper = i+9
    SQL3 = SQL1 + str(lower) + ' and ' + str(upper)
    data2 = pd.read_sql(SQL3, conn)
    print(data2)
    data = data.append(data2)
```

Comment: Can you specify a bit? Do you mean that the resulting `data` has only 10 rows? And does each `print(data2)` in the for loop print the correct data?

Comment: Hello. Yes, it only prints 10 rows to the csv. I seem to have found a method that works by using the chunksize argument in read_sql(). It took 3.7 hours to produce a 8GB CSV of what I think is over 28 million rows by 17 columns. Just to get the length of it is taking forever. Would it have been better to save it as HDF5? It all seemed so simple at first. Sorry if this is bird-walking a bit. I'll start a new question if needed.