# Python 3.4 cx_Oracle and Pandas: Iterating Over Chunksize

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle, chunks

So I ran into [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810228/python-3-4-loop-and-append-why-not-working-with-cx-oracle-and-pandas) with trying to get 1 million rows at a time from a 29 million row (by 17 column) materialized view. This seemed to be a good alternative (using the chunksize argument in the pandas read_sql function).

The trouble is, I don't think "chunk" clears itself from memory after each iteration because I get a memory error when getting chunks of 1 million rows (I can usually just get 1 million rows in about 10 seconds).

Is there a simple way to get around the memory error?

```
import cx_Oracle as cx
import pandas as pd
conn = cx.Connection("username/password@server")
data = pd.DataFrame([])
SQL1 = '''SELECT * FROM TABLE_MV'''
for chunk in pd.read_sql(SQL1, conn, chunksize=1000000):
    data = data.append(chunk)
```

Update: I'm ultimately trying to write the data to a CSV file (though I would write to HDF5 if that's better; I'm still new to this process) to read back into Pandas later.
I tried this approach, but still working out issues:

```
import cx_Oracle as cx
import pandas as pd
conn = cx.Connection("username/password@server")
data = pd.DataFrame([])
#Get header and first row
SQL1 = '''SELECT * FROM TABLE_MV where rownum < 2'''
data = pd.read_sql(SQL1, conn)
SQL2 = '''SELECT * FROM TABLE_MV where rownum between 2 and 30'''
data.to_csv(filename.csv')
with open(filename.csv', 'a') as f:
    for chunk in pd.read_sql(SQL2, conn, chunksize=10):
        chunk.to_csv(f, header=False)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Apologies if this is not you but are you creating multiple users: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4392566/dance-party and if so why?

Comment: That's absolutely absurd. I can't believe you would insinuate such a thing...but, alas, it's true. I keep different accounts for work vs. home because I work on different projects and I prefer not to enter my personal e-mail credentials into my work computer. Is that okay? Please don't take away my work account.

Comment: Just an observation I don't know whether this is disallowed, the main issue are people who serially upvote their own questions to get rep or when people get banned for poor behaviour and keep creating new accounts to continue not following the site rules

Comment: Oh okay. I'm just a newb trying to get along.

Comment: it may be worth asking on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ this will be the definitive answer, so long as you don't violate the site rules then I can't see there being a problem

Comment: I'll ask when I get home (my work account doesn't have the required rep points to do so yet). Thanks!